# Elastic collision between moving particles in python: why is kinetic energy not conserved?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am trying to code a particle simulation in pygame but am having trouble coding the collisions between particles. All the collisions are elastic so kinetic energy should be conserved. However, I am experiencing two main problems:

1. Particles speed up and up until they get out of control
2. Particles clump together and stop moving

I would really appreciate any insight to help solve these problems.

I used this document (http://www.vobarian.com/collisions/2dcollisions2.pdf) to help calculate the new velocities of the particles after the collision. The mass of all the particles is the same so I have ignored their mass in my calculations.
Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import random
import numpy

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 500
NUM_BALLS = 2


#setup
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Simulation")

class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y , radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.xvel = random.randint(1,5)
        self.yvel = random.randint(1,5)

    def Draw_circle(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, (255,0,0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
for ball in balls:
    ball.Draw_circle()

pygame.display.update()


balls = []    
for turn in range(NUM_BALLS):
balls.append(Particle(random.randint(20,WIDTH-20),random.randint(20,HEIGHT-20),20))


run = True
while run:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

for ball in balls:
     if (ball.x + ball.radius) <= WIDTH or (ball.x - ball.radius) >= 0:
       ball.x += ball.xvel
     if (ball.x + ball.radius) > WIDTH or (ball.x - ball.radius) < 0:
         ball.xvel *= -1
         ball.x += ball.xvel
     if (ball.y + ball.radius) <= HEIGHT or (ball.y - ball.radius) >= 0:
         ball.y += ball.yvel
     if (ball.y + ball.radius) > HEIGHT or (ball.y - ball.radius) < 0:
         ball.yvel *= -1
         ball.y += ball.yvel

#code for collision between balls
for ball in balls:
    for i in range(len(balls)):
        for j in range (i+1, len(balls)):
            d = (balls[j].x-balls[i].x)**2 + (balls[j].y-balls[i].y)**2
            if d < (balls[j].radius + balls[i].radius)**2:
                print("collision")
                n  = (balls[i].x-balls[j].x, balls[i].y-balls[j].y) #normal vector
                un = n/ numpy.sqrt((balls[i].x-balls[j].x)**2 + (balls[i].y-balls[j].y)**2) #unit normal vector
                ut = numpy.array((-un[1],un[0])) #unit tangent vector
                u1n = numpy.vdot(un, (balls[j].xvel, balls[j].yvel)) #initial velocity in normal direction for first ball
                v1t = numpy.vdot(ut, (balls[j].xvel, balls[j].yvel)) #initial velocity in tangent direction (remains unchanged)
                u2n = numpy.vdot(un, (balls[i].xvel, balls[i].yvel)) #second ball
                v2t = numpy.vdot(ut, (balls[i].xvel, balls[i].yvel))
                v1n = u2n
                v2n = u1n
                v1n *= un
                v2n *= un
                v1t *= ut
                v2t *= ut
                v1 = v1n + v1t #ball 1 final velocity
                v2 = v2n + v2t #ball 2 final velocity
                balls[j].xvel = int(numpy.vdot(v1, (1,0))) #splitting final velocities into x and y components again
                balls[j].yvel = int(numpy.vdot(v1, (0,1)))
                balls[i].xvel = int(numpy.vdot(v2, (1,0)))
                balls[i].yvel = int(numpy.vdot(v2, (0,1)))

redrawGameWindow()
pygame.time.delay(20)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem where the things would stick together is simple, even though you always checked for collision, the time where it would actually recognise it would be when the circles would be past touching but slightly into each other. The circles now bounce and move a little. However they have not moved enough to completely to not be touching, this mean the bounce again and it goes in a loop. I made code that fixes this, but you have to change the bounce function and use your code, as mine is not that perfect, but functional.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import random
import numpy

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 500
NUM_BALLS = 2


#setup
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Simulation")

class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y , radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.xvel = random.randint(1,5)
        self.yvel = random.randint(1,5)
        self.colideCheck = []
    def Draw_circle(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, (255,0,0), (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.radius)


def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    for ball in balls:
        ball.Draw_circle()
    pygame.display.update()
def bounce(v1,v2, mass1 = 1, mass2 = 1):




    #i Tried my own bouncing mechanism, but doesn't work completly well, add yours here




    multi1 = mass1/(mass1+mass2)
    multi2 = mass2/(mass1+mass2)
    deltaV2 = (multi1*v1[0]-multi2*v2[0],multi1*v1[1]-multi2*v2[1])
    deltaV1 = (multi2*v2[0]-multi1*v1[0],multi2*v2[1]-multi1*v1[1])
    print("preVelocities:",v1,v2)
    return deltaV1,deltaV2
def checkCollide(circ1Cord,circ1Rad,circ2Cord,circ2Rad):
    tryDist = circ1Rad+circ2Rad
    actualDist = dist(circ1Cord,circ2Cord)
    if dist(circ1Cord,circ2Cord) <= tryDist:
        return True
    return False
def dist(pt1,pt2):
    dX = pt1[0]-pt2[0]
    dY = pt1[1]-pt2[1]
    return (dX**2 + dY**2)**0.5
balls = []  
for turn in range(NUM_BALLS):
    balls.append(Particle(random.randint(60,WIDTH-60),random.randint(60,HEIGHT-60),60))


run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    for ball in balls:
         if (ball.x + ball.radius) <= WIDTH and (ball.x - ball.radius) >= 0:
             ball.x += ball.xvel
         else:
             ball.xvel *= -1
             ball.x += ball.xvel
         if (ball.y + ball.radius) <= HEIGHT and (ball.y - ball.radius) >= 0:
             ball.y += ball.yvel
         else:
             ball.yvel *= -1
             ball.y += ball.yvel
    for ball in balls:
        for secBallCheck in balls:
            if secBallCheck not in ball.colideCheck and ball!= secBallCheck and checkCollide((ball.x,ball.y),ball.radius,(secBallCheck.x,secBallCheck.y),secBallCheck.radius):
                print("COLLIDE")
                vel1,vel2 = bounce((ball.xvel,ball.yvel),(secBallCheck.xvel,secBallCheck.yvel))
                print(vel1,vel2)
                ball.xvel = vel1[0]
                ball.yvel = vel1[1]
                ball.colideCheck.append(secBallCheck)
                secBallCheck.xvel = vel2[0]
                secBallCheck.yvel = vel2[1]
                secBallCheck.colideCheck.append(ball)
            elif not checkCollide((ball.x,ball.y),ball.radius,(secBallCheck.x,secBallCheck.y),secBallCheck.radius):
                if ball in secBallCheck.colideCheck:
                    secBallCheck.colideCheck.remove(ball)
                    ball.colideCheck.remove(secBallCheck)
    redrawGameWindow()
    pygame.time.delay(20)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

In `v1 = v1n + v1t`, `v1n` is a vector, but `v1t` is a scalar.

So, the value `v1t` gets added to both components of the `v1n` vector, which causes the error.

You want to add the tangential velocity as a vector, so you should do just like you did for the normal velocities:

```
v1n *= un
v2n *= un
v1t *= ut
v2t *= ut
```

Note that using the same variable for two very different things, the vector and its norm, makes your code more difficult to understand and can lead to errors - as it just did. You should probably rename your variables in a more consistent way, in order to make the differences clearer.

Also, `ut` must be a numpy array, but you made it a tuple. Consider the difference:

With a tuple

```
>>> t = (3, 4)
>>> 3*t
(3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4)
```

With a np.array:

```
>>> t = np.array((3, 4))
>>> 3*t
array([ 9, 12])
```

So, you have to change

```
ut = (-un[1],un[0])
```

into

```
ut = numpy.array((-un[1],un[0]))
```

Comment: I have tried this but now all the balls just seem to stick together immediately without rebounding off each other at all?

Comment: There was another problem with `ut`, see my edit. Note that it is impossible to test your code, as it is not complete enough to run it, even in a reduced version. Consider creating a [mcve] if there are more bugs in your code.